# How do I Insert Overwrite with parquet format?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am have two parquet file in azure data lake gen2 I want to Insert Overwrite onw with other. I was trying the same in azure data bricks by doing below.

Reading from data lake to azure.

```
val cs_mbr_prov_1 = spark.read.format("parquet")
    .option("header","true")
    .load(s"${SourcePath}/cs_mbr_prov")

cs_mbr_prov_1.createOrReplaceTempView("cs_mbr_prov")
```

```
val cs_mbr_prov_stg = spark.read.format("parquet")
    .option("header","true")
    .load(s"${SourcePath}/cs_mbr_prov_stg_1")

cs_mbr_prov_stg.createOrReplaceTempView("cs_mbr_prov_stg")
```

```
var res =spark.sql(
    s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE cs_br_prov " +
    s"SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('IND_ID',stg.IND_ID,'CUST_NBR',stg.CUST_NBR,'SRC_ID',stg.SRC_ID, "+
          s"'SRC_SYS_CD',stg.SRC_SYS_CD,'OUTBOUND_ID',stg.OUTBOUND_ID,'OPP_ID',stg.OPP_ID, " +
          s"'CAMPAIGN_CD',stg.CAMPAIGN_CD,'TREAT_KEY',stg.TREAT_KEY,'PROV_KEY',stg.PROV_KEY, " +
          s"'INSERTDATE',stg.INSERTDATE,'UPDATEDATE',stg.UPDATEDATE,'CONTACT_KEY',stg.CONTACT_KEY
    ) AS key, " + 
s"stg.MEM_KEY,stg.INDV_ID,stg.MBR_ID,stg.OPP_DT,stg.SEG_ID,stg.MODA,stg.E_KEY, " +
s"stg.TREAT_RUNDATETIME from cs_br_prov_stg stg")
```

Error I am getting:

> AnalysisException: unknown requires that the data to be inserted have the same number of columns as the target table: target table has 20 column(s) but the inserted data has 9 column(s), including 0 partition column(s) having constant value(s).

But having same no.of colums in both.

Comment: Could you share DDL of table cs_br_prov?  Have you tried creating that table as [**CREATE AS SELECT**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html) yet?

Comment: Actually i don't have any table. I have table in on-prem database i am loading that into azure in parquet format and i am trying to do above one.